# how to install .net framework? if not already installed using autorun.inf

Tags: batch-file

I need the file autorun.inf with this content:

```
[autorun]
open=file.bat
icon=icon.ico
```

and file.bat with this content for detect setup.exe and framework4 (if the last don't exist):

```
REG HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full /v Version :rechek 
IF %errorlevel%==0 GOTO INSTALL start setup.exe exit GOTO eof :INSTALL dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe GOTO rechek
```

What is the error in the file .bat file?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a not tested batch code which makes more sense then your batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "RetryCount=0"
:ReCheckFramework
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" /v Version>nul 2>nul 
if not errorlevel 1 goto EndFrameworkInstall
start "Install FrameWork" /wait dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe
set /A RetryCount+=1
if %RetryCount% LSS 3 goto ReCheckFramework
:EndFrameworkInstall
endlocal
```

Testing a batch file should be always done by opening a command prompt window and running the batch file from within this console window. Then syntax errors and errors on parameter list of commands and applications can be easily seen.

`reg.exe` requires as first parameter the action to do, here **query**. And you forget the double quotes around registry key as it contains spaces.

Also writing nearly all commands in one line is also wrong.

Well, best would be to really check version of installed .NET Framework 4 in case of a newer version is already installed then what is put on CD/DVD.